# TinyMCE 3.x stripping out empty classes

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce-3

I'm using TinyMCE 3.x and can't find the documentation for a problem I'm having.

If I use the html editor to add an empty element such as `<div class="clearfix"></div>` or `<span class="clearfix"></span>`, the editor removes these automatically.

Is there a way to tell it to stop stripping out empty elements?

I have found

```
extended_valid_elements :  "#div, #span",
```

which almost fixes it. If I enable this and add `<div class="clearfix"></div>`, it replaces it with `<div>&nbsp;</div>`, so adds a space but removes the class.

Comment: hey, try `extended_valid_elements :  "#div[class], #span[class]",`

Comment: that seems to have done it. I've added `[class|id]` and that seems to be working. Unfortunately, I'm having to use the way back machine to get the documentation for 3.x! >.<   if you add the answer, I'll give you the credit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `class` attribute seems to get stripped out, so try to make it valid like this:

```
extended_valid_elements : "#div[class], #span[class]"
```